# Angular-ui-router not rendering templates with django

Tags: django, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am working on a django project that relies on angularjs and having trouble implementing `angular-ui-router framework`.

As mentioned in documentation I have included `ui.router` as a dependency,

```
app = angular.module('myApp',['restangular','ui.router',])
```

configured the states as follows,

```
app.config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('landing',{
      url: '/',
      template:"<p> somethings here.</p>"
    })
  }]);
```

in `base.html` file i bootstrap the django project with angularjs as required
`ng-app=myApp`.

and in `index.html` which inherits `base.html`

```
<div ui-view>
  <i>nothing here but this text</i>
</div>
```

my `urls.py`,

```
url(r'^$',home,name="homepage")
```

This does not work, `ui-router` never includes the `inline template` in `index.html`. `index.html` always loads `nothing here but this text`. I have looked at as much questions asked here but are not helping. What am I missing, is this specific to django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that these lines should make it:

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider',function($urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  }]);
```

Check the working [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/N7fNoP6wl6sKnfFKxflZ?p=preview)

Also check:

- [`otherwise()` for invalid routes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#otherwise-for-invalid-routes)

Comment: Great, enjoy awesome ui-router :)